# Why won't my bool variable change its value

Tags: python, operator-keyword

So, i'm having a hard time with this code i wrote. The way it should be working is switching the bool `is_on` variable between `True` and `False`, and while `is_on` is `True`, it keeps printing some text. Except it does change from `False` to `True` the first time i press the hotkey, but doesn't change it from `True` to `False` when i press it again.

```
import time
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Controller as controller

is_on = False
def for_canonical(input):
    return lambda key: input(listener.canonical(key))
def on_off(is_on):
    is_on = not is_on
    loop(is_on).start()
def loop(is_on):
    while is_on == True:
        print("some text")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("some text")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("some text")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("some text")
        time.sleep(1)
hotkey = keyboard.HotKey(keyboard.HotKey.parse("<alt>+n"), lambda: on_off(is_on).start())
listener = keyboard.Listener(
on_press=for_canonical(hotkey.press),
on_release=for_canonical(hotkey.release))
listener.start()
```

I spent a lot of time rewriting the code, using a lot of different methods, operators and etc., and i have no idea why it doesn't work. This is the shortest and cleanest code i wrote, which i decided to keep. I really need some help :(

Comment: What happened  adding concept of  `global` keyword doesn't helped ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In Python, `funct` arguments are passed by value, which means that when you pass `is_on` to the `on_off` funct, it creates a `new local` variable with the same name. Modifying this local variable inside the function does not affect the `original` `is_on` variable outside the function.
- you can use the `global` keyword inside the `on_off` function to indicate that you want to modify the `global is_on variable`.

```
is_on = False

def on_off():
    global is_on
    is_on = not is_on
    # rest of your code
```

Comment: I had a strong feeling it had something to do with the `is_on` variable not being passed to the function, but i thought giving arguments to the function does that (passes global variables to it), i will look into that, thanks a lot for the answer. Also, your code doesn't work because of `on_press=hotkey.press` and `on_release=hotkey.release`, because alt key needs to be canonized (is that a thing? I didn't research this whole canonical thing too deeply) first. That's what the `for_canonical` function is there for :p